# How to delete file and its folder if there is one, in shell?

Tags: shell, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a shell script that is copying some files for a S3 bucket (aws) on local, then it is copying it to another place (it cannot do it directly, because of some authorization), but the idea is that the image may be in some folder and the shell is creating it locally, but it is deleting just the image and I found that after execution I have some empty folders. So my question is how to delete the folder too, if it is present in the name?

My shell part that copies and deletes:

```
aws s3 cp s3://$SRC_BUCKET/$PHOTO_NAME $PHOTO_NAME --profile $SRC_PROFILE
# copy to other place
rm $PHOTO_NAME # here PHOTO_NAME may have the parent folder in it (a.jpg, 
               # or b/a.jpg) and I would like to delete the b folder too
```

---

I have updated my code, based on the answer below, but it seems not to do what expected: the temporary directory is created, but all is done outside of it... My code looks like this:

```
dir="$(mktemp aws-sync-XXXXX)"
pushd "$dir"
COUNT=1
until [ $COUNT -gt $MAX_COUNT ]; do
        aws s3 cp s3://$SRC_BUCKET/$PHOTO_NAME $PHOTO_NAME --profile $SRC_PROFILE
        # copy to other place
        rm $PHOTO_NAME

        (( MESSAGES_COUNT+=1 ))
    fi
done
popd
rm -rf "$dir"
```

Answer (score 2):

fundamentally, you're setting yourself up for some race conditions (what if the folder already existed, &c). A better way to do this is creating a fresh folder *before* you run this script, then run it inside there. So:

```
dir="$(mktemp aws-sync-XXXXX)"
pushd "$dir"

# do stuff

popd
rm -rf "$dir"
```

That will ensure you delete everything your temporary command created, and nothing more.

Comment: `do stuff` means my lines? You are right: what if the folder already exists?! I suppose that it will not create it again, just save the image inside... But your approach is interesting

Comment: ok, but what if I do not want to sync the s3? I just want to copy some files

Comment: What do you mean by "not sync to s3 but just copy some files"? What I'm proposing is not specific to S3: it's for any command that creates garbage in your current directory. You clean that up by running it in a new directory, doing your thing, and deleting the whole directory afterwards.

Comment: So you are saying to change the `$PHOTO_NAME`? because now it is saving the image in `./a.jpg` or `./b/a.jpg` even if I add you lines. It seems that it creates the temp folder, but not downloading in it...

Comment: no, I'm saying your case is too ill-defined. I don't care about what the aws tool does, for all I care it can create a thousand directories and files. If all you want to do is clean up whatever mess it created, instead of looking for that mess, just do it all in a new (empty) directory and delete *that*, instead. there, problem averted. stop caring about aws, just take a sledge hammer to it and you're done.

Comment: I have just tried to put my code of copy-to-local in the your do stuff place, but I can see that the photos ace copied outside the temp directory...